# custom exception not being caught

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, codeigniter-3

Having this custom exception:

```
class TokenException extends Exception 
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($message, $token)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->token = $token;

        parent::__construct($message, 1);
    }
}
```

And this code which uses it:

```
public function visit()
{
    try {

        // validate input token

        // actions

    }
    catch (TokenException $e) {

        logdebug('TokenException'); // logs "TokenException"

        $res['relogin'] = 1;
        $res['error'] = $e->getMessage() . ' token: ' . $token;

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {

        logdebug('Exception'); // logs "Exception"

        $res['error'] = $e->getMessage() . ' token: ' . $token;

    }
    finally {
        $this->output($res);
    }
}
```

Despite in the validation it's throwing the TokenException:

```
throw new TokenException('Invalid token. It does not belong to any user', $token);
```

It skips the TokenException catch and enters the one for Exception, displaying the token error message.

What's wrong here?

**EDIT**:

Here's the code in more detail. It uses Codeigniter MVC pattern:

This is the parent controller for the public API involved:

```
class Apicontroller extends MX_Controller
{

    /**
     * 
     * @var stdClass $user
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * Load user model
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->model('users_model', 'users');
    }


    protected function output($data)
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    // other code...

}
```

The code where the Exception is not caught:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Apicontroller.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../TokenException.php';


class Apisellercontroller extends Apicontroller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('apiseller_model', 'apiseller');
        $this->load->model('log_model', 'logger');
        $this->load->model('alerts_model', 'alerts');
    }

    // inserts/updates data of a visit made by a sales agent to a client from an external app
    public function visit()
    {
        try {

            $res = [];

            // get api token and user
            $user = $this->input->post('user');
            $token = $this->input->post('token');
            $visit = $this->input->post('data');

            $this->validateRequest($user, $token, $visit);

            // Get user by token from the users model
            $this->user = $this->users->getByToken($token);

            $this->apiseller->setUser($this->user);

            $visit['sellers_id'] = $this->apiseller->getSeller()->id;

            // Insert/update
            $this->load->model('visits_model');

            $res['id'] = $this->visits_model->save($visit);

        }
        catch (TokenException $e) {

            $res['relogin'] = 1;
            $res['error'] = $e->getMessage() . ' token: ' . $token . ' user: ' . $user;

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {

            $res['error'] = $e->getMessage() . ' token: ' . $token . ' user: ' . $user;

        }
        finally {
            $this->output($res);
        }
    }

    private function validateRequest($user, $token, $data)
    {
        if (empty($user)) {
            throw new Exception('User id not received');
        }
        if (empty($token)) {
            throw new Exception('Session token not received');
        }
        if (empty($data)) {
            throw new Exception('Request data not available');
        }

        // Check token validity for user
        $this->apiseller->checkTokenValid($user, $token);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Model used to check validity of token (and throws the TokenExcepcion in case it's invalid):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Api_model.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../modules/api/TokenException.php';

class Apiseller_model extends Api_model
{

    public function checkTokenValid($currentUser, $token)
    {
        $user = $this->getUserByToken($token);
        if (empty($user)) {
            throw new TokenException('User not found for specified token', $token);
        }

        if ($user->name != $currentUser) {
            throw new TokenException("Invalid token. It doesn't match the specified user", $token);
        }
    }

    // other code...

}
```

Comment: It may not be what you think it is. Try logging `get_class($e)` to make sure it is a TokenException.

Comment: @aynber: It prints "Exception". Looks like it's not thrown as a TokenException.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try parent::__construct($message, 1); as first line? If not, I understand it overrides the attributes set previously...

```
class TokenException extends Exception 
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($message, $token)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, 1);
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->token = $token;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said. You're right in that I should call the parent's construct first. Anyway, it's still throwing the exception as Exception instead of TokenException

Comment: What about namespaces and uses? If TokenException is declared inside a namescape, it must be included using "use" where it is caugth and where it is thrown

Comment: I'm not using namespaces in this case

Comment: I tried to reproduce with not success. It enters in the proper TokenException. Could you show entire code? Just make sure that no Exception (base Exception) is thrown before your `throw new TokenException()`. It would be the only reason I can see in this behaviour.

Comment: There's a lot of code involved, but I've added the most relevant parts. You may check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The exception beeing thrown is obviously not an instance of TokenException, therefore I suggest that you should take a look at the stacktrace to see, where this exception really comes from:

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php

```
echo $e->getTraceAsString();die;
```

You can also check if your exception was passed as "previous"; that would mean it was wrapped in other part of your code:

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php

```
var_dump($e->getPrevious());die;
```